# ng-init in angularjs didn't work for me

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I try to set the dropdown to current month which is Oct but it doesn't work, any clue guys?

http://plnkr.co/edit/qtPvCy4phNQW6I6IPQyr?p=preview

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var d = new Date();
        var month = new Array();

        var this_year = d.getFullYear();

        month[0] = "January " + this_year;
        month[1] = "February " + this_year;
        month[2] = "March " + this_year;
        month[3] = "April " + this_year;
        month[4] = "May " + this_year;
        month[5] = "June " + this_year;
        month[6] = "July " + this_year;
        month[7] = "August " + this_year;
        month[8] = "September " + this_year;
        month[9] = "October " + this_year;
        month[10] = "November " + this_year;
        month[11] = "December " + this_year;

        $scope.months = month;

        $scope.this_month = month[d.getMonth()] + " " + this_year; // won't work?
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default month by assigning current month to `model` selected_month.

```
$scope.selected_month = $scope.months[d.getMonth()];
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cI3D8gNrCIvx992qZNZc?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

> Problem solved: ngInit used for set default values, and you tried to set that but in wrong way, see this example please

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  var d = new Date();
    var month = new Array();

    var this_year = d.getFullYear();

    month[0] = "January " + this_year;
    month[1] = "February " + this_year;
    month[2] = "March " + this_year;
    month[3] = "April " + this_year;
    month[4] = "May " + this_year;
    month[5] = "June " + this_year;
    month[6] = "July " + this_year;
    month[7] = "August " + this_year;
    month[8] = "September " + this_year;
    month[9] = "October " + this_year;
    month[10] = "November " + this_year;
    month[11] = "December " + this_year;

    $scope.months = month;
    
   $scope.this_month = month[d.getMonth()]; // won't work?
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.x" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js" data-semver="1.0.7"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <select style="position: relative;margin-top: -50px;" class="pull-right" ng-model="selected_month" ng-options="m for m in months" ng-init="selected_month = this_month">
          </select>
          </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You most define a function on controller and called method on ng-init. 
for example

```
ng-init="this_month()"
```

Change this line on controller:

```
$scope.this_month = month[d.getMonth()] + " " + this_year; // won't work?
```

to:

```
 $scope.this_month = //Change this line....
        function(){
              $scope.selected_month = $scope.months[d.getMonth()];
        };
```